# Including Google hosted JQuery using wp_enqueue_script()

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am using JQuery on my Wordpress installation using wp_enqueue_script() so that other plugins can find it easily and do not try to add another installation.

My JQuery includes became old and I am thinking of updating it. I can change the code and mention newer installation but I want a proper way of doing it, so that newer stable version get included from Google hosted JQuery without me changing anything.

I think I have only this much code in my theme's function file:

```
if( !is_admin()){
  wp_deregister_script('jquery'); 
  wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js', false, '1.3.2'); 
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

Now, I am looking for the code which can include stable version as soon it came on Google.!

Comment: I have added the code in use on my theme for adding JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that you de-register WordPress' original copy of JQuery and JQuery-UI using [wp_unregister_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script), before using wp_enqueue_script for the latest ones. WordPress uses jQuery in safe mode, so make sure you set your copy to that too.

This is what I do

```
wp_unregister_script('jquery');
wp_unregister_script('jquery-ui-core');
```

If you look at the documentation under "Default scripts included with WordPress", you will find the script handle WordPress uses for its default scripts. When you enqueue the latest jQuery, make sure to use the same handle too so other plugins which enqueues jquery can find it too.

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery', $pathTojQuery);
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core', $pathTojQueryUI);
```

Comment: Hi, I included Google hosted jquery in my WordPress without unregistering the core script...Do you think this will create a problem to have two jqueries on my site?

Comment: and what would the path to jquery look like if you were using the Google hosted vershion ?   Can you please show me? //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript

Comment: I put these functions into my wordpress site but it broke everything. do you wrap them in another function?

Comment: I put them directly in my custom functions file, which broke it, but then I got a script, which seems to make them work now. However, the jQuery is acting buggy...If you have a moment sometime and inclination, I'd appreciate it if you'd share your opinion... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608809/how-is-it-that-changing-positioning-on-css-can-affect-dropability-in-jquery

Comment: do you think it's necessary to enque for the jquery ui css? http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/base/jquery-ui.css

Answer (score 0):

Google allows you to link to the latest version of jQuery by making the requested version number less precise.

For example:

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js will always be the 1.4.3 version

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js will always be the latest 1.x version

Note that changes in jQuery could break your jQuery-dependent code, so there's both an upside and a downside to this.